# Show dynamic content based on clicked tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to display content for a particular tab dynamically.

If a particular navigation tab is clicked it has to show the respective contents on the right.

Currently, it's showing all the tab information together. Is there a way this can be handled using jquery/js.

Tab:

```
<div class="ibm-tab-section">
            <ul class="ibm-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li><a aria-selected="true" role="tab" href="#example2b-tab1">Example 2b Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab2">Example 2b Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab3">Example 2b Tab 3</a></li>
                <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab4">Example 2b Tab 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Tab 1 content:

```
    <div id="example2b-tab1" class="ibm-tabs-content">
            <p>Example 2b Tab 1 contents</p>
        </div>
```

Tab 2 content :

```
<div id="example2b-tab2" class="ibm-tabs-content">
            <p>Example 2b Tab 2 contents</p>
            <form>
                <p>
                    <select>
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                        <option value="1">Mr.</option>
                        <option value="1">Mrs.</option>
                        <option value="1">Dude</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Hide all the `.ibm-tabs-content` elements using CSS
- On click of the `a` element, hide `.ibm-tabs-content` element and show the respective content element on the basis of `href` attribute that is mapped.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#example2b-tab1").show();
});
$('.ibm-tabs li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.ibm-tabs-content').hide();
  let IDSelector = $(this).attr('href');
  $(IDSelector).show();
})
```

```css
.ibm-tabs-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ibm-tab-section">
  <ul class="ibm-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a aria-selected="true" role="tab" href="#example2b-tab1">Example 2b Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab2">Example 2b Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab3">Example 2b Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab4">Example 2b Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="example2b-tab1" class="ibm-tabs-content">
  <p>Example 2b Tab 1 contents</p>
</div>


<div id="example2b-tab2" class="ibm-tabs-content">
  <p>Example 2b Tab 2 contents</p>
  <form>
    <p>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">Mr.</option>
        <option value="1">Mrs.</option>
        <option value="1">Dude</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rayon30 Solved 90% of my problem but the page by default before clicking needs to show tab1.

Comment: @SurajPrasad If your problem is solved then mark this as an answer.

Comment: @KishanVaishnav as mentioned in my previous comment I was waiting for the final piece of solution

Comment: @SurajPrasad Which was not mentioned in the question. Anyway, I have edited the answer to show the first element. It will be visible in a few minutes.

Comment: @SurajPrasad Since my edit was rejected add "$(function() {
        $("#example2b-tab1").show();
    });" just before .click function.

Comment: @KishanVaishnav - Thanks for the edit. Another approach would be to use CSS to show `.example2b-tab1` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show the content of different tabs on click on the tabs using jquery and javascript by using the style property of display and making it as none.